# Ordering data inside aggregate function

Tags: sql

The time is not sorted inside aggregate function in this query:

```
SELECT id,
       aggregate(time)
FROM   (SELECT *
        FROM   TABLE
        ORDER  BY time) AS foo
GROUP  BY something;
```

How can I sort by column inside group by expression?

Comment: If you want the final result ordered you need to put the desired `ORDER BY` on the outer query. Your example query is invalid anyway `GROUP  BY something` and `SELECT id` isn't valid (except perhaps in MySQL...)

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @SWeko, my aggregate function depends on the order of input data

Comment: Well, in general it shouldn't (none of the built-in aggregates do). My feeling is that you are using something wrong, that's why I'm asking what are you trying to do, there might be an easier way?

Comment: @ElectricHedgehog: What database and version are you using? The answer to this question (like *almost* all SQL questions) depends on the database and verson.

Comment: @Sweko: "Well, in general it shouldn't (none of the built-in aggregates do)." What database are you talking about? Pretty much all the major databases have at least one aggregate function that accepts an ORDER BY clause.

Comment: @MarkByers: yes, concat would be an example of an aggregate that depends on the input order. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have an `ORDER BY` on a subquery and you don't need it.

You can add an `ORDER BY` to the result of the aggregate function, but that won't affect how the aggregate function calculates its results.

If you want to affect the order in which the aggregate function looks at its arguments then you can can add an `ORDER BY` to the aggregate function but only in some databases and in some situations.

```
SELECT id, aggregate(time ORDER BY time)
FROM   (SELECT *  FROM   TABLE) AS foo
GROUP  BY something;
```

**Examples**

- [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES)
- MySQL's [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: There is also `SUM(value) OVER (ORDER BY x)` used for running totals etc.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot sort inside a derived table, what you can do is

```
SELECT id,
       aggregate(time)
FROM   (SELECT *
        FROM   TABLE
        ) AS foo
GROUP  BY something;
ORDER  BY aggregate(time)
```